# Scala system.shutdown not working

Tags: scala, akka, actor, remote-actors

I am sending a message from one actor to kill another actor. The receiver actor executes `context.system.shutdown`. Although the actor is perfectly receiving the message and executing the code specified in the case statement, it just wont shut down. What is going wrong?

Receive method of the receiver actor.

```
def receive = {
  ...

  case "KILL" => context.system.shutdown
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
case "KILL" => context.system.shutdown()
```

should shut down the whole actor system. With the code you've given I don't see why it would not. As you have tagged your question with *remote-actors*, I could imagine that you might have some logic to restart the remote actor system on failure.

However, to just kill one actor you would not shut down the whole system but rather stop the one actor:

```
case "KILL" => context.stop(self)
```

Comment: Actually there few are actors in that system that keep running while system.shutdown() is executed. So will it force stop those running actors or wait for them to stop processing first.